# Selenium. Всплывание окна на передний фон

Tags: c#, selenium

Если запустить слудующий код, то при каждой итерации цикла браузер будет всплывать на передний фон и получать фокус.

```
public class Program
{
  private static void Main()
  {
    var driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://i.imgur.com/cdA7SBB.jpg");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      var ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
      ss.SaveAsFile("D:/imgs/i.jpg");
    }
  }
}
```

Вопрос: почему так происходит и можно ли как то это выключить?
headless мод не подходит.

Похоже что это происходит всегда когда Selenium нужно сохранить/прочитать файл или запустить процесс.

**Update:**
Спасибо большое [Florent B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887618/florent-b) за помощь в решении данного вопроса. Вот правильный ответ [Selenium. Bring-up window on the front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243989/selenium-bring-up-window-on-the-front)

Comment: тебе нужно, чтобы браузер не получал фокус и не мешал тебе?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, да.

Answer (score 2):

Смею предположить, что такое поведение это необходимость при снятии скриншота. Во время обычных действий Selenium не требует активации окна.

Чтобы окно браузера не мешало, можно запускать его в докере. Вот образы и краткая инструкция - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

Comment: "Смею предположить, что такое поведение это необходимость при снятии скриншота." - Вполне возможно. Получение скриншота из окна на заднем плане в Windows не всегда возможно. Это зависит от того, как окно выводит изображение, и от версии Windows (т.к. механика DWM меняется).

Comment: @suit, @MSDN.WhiteKnight, по тому что я вижу локально проблема как раз таки не в снятии скриншота. Если вставить задержку между `GetScreenshot()` и `SaveAsFile()` то можно убедится в том что окно браузера всплывает на `SaveAsFile()` - то есть это прямой доступ к диску. Так же в своих тестах я заметил что `Process.Start()` в паре с `Process.WaitForExit()` - воспроизводит подобное поведение, не уверен что у них одинаковая природа, но похоже что они одинаково тригерят всплывание окна на передний фон с захватом фокуса.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan, вполне возможно, что фактическое снятие скриншота происходит в момент вызова метода `SaveAsFile()`. С c# мало знаком, в питоне метод один (вместе с сохранением) - `driver.save_screenshot('file.png')` - и во время вызова окно активируется

Comment: @AntonKomyshan а если скриншот не в файл, в а память сохранять? Не очень понятен пример про Process.Start. Если запускается оконное приложение, вполне ожидаемо, что оно будет в фокусе. При запуске через функцию ShellExecute это поведение иногда можно изменить.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, если `Process.Start` запускает оконное приложение и само это оконное приложение оказывается в фокусе - тут проблем нет, проблема возникает когда я запускаю через Process.Start - консольное приложение без окна, то на `Process.WaitForExit()` - всплывает браузер... почему? пока не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

это непростая задача и ее сложно сконфигурировать "через настройки", но я могу предложить достаточно простое решение для вас.

1. развернуть у себя docker. [Инструкция](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) для Windows машин
2. развернуть Standalone Chrome. Более подробная инструкция [тут](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#standalone-chrome-and-firefox)

   `docker run --rm -d -p 4444:4444 --name hub selenium/standalone-chrome`
3. Настроить Capacity для работы с удаленным драйвером

   ```
   var uri = 'uri_to_your_hub'; // в данном случае будет http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
   var capabilities =  new ChromeOptions().ToCapabilities();
   var commandTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
   var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(uri),capabilities,commandTimeout)
   ```

Таким образом, браузер будет запускаться внутри контейнера, вы подключайтесь у нему удаленно и работаете. Вы можете перейти по ссылке http://localhost:4444/wd/hub и увидеть запущенные сеансы и даже посмотреть на скриншот конкретного сеанса.

Также можно добиться того, чтобы все запустилось от имени системного пользователя. Тогда вы тоже ничего не увидите.

**UPDATE**

можно воспользоваться PhantomJSDriver.

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities();
dc.SetCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", "path/to/phantomjs");
var driver = = new PhantomJSDriver(ds);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://i.imgur.com/cdA7SBB.jpg");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  var ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
  ss.SaveAsFile("D:/imgs/i.jpg");
}
```

**UDPATE 2**

webdriver иногда фокусит окно при взаимодействий. Необязательно, чтобы выполнить действия, даже если просто поищете элемент. 
По этой причине нет решений, чтобы тесты запускались в интерактивном режиме и при этом нет фокусились. Для этого придумали другие решения, такие как контейнеры, PhantomJS, HtmlUnit, --headless(с 59 версии хрома).

Comment: да конечно же я смотрел и гуглил на счёт того что бы запускать это просто в VM/Docker, но это не то чего хотелось бы. Может есть WINAPI с помощью которого можно задизейблить данное поведение. Я думаю что данное поведение активации окна при IO операциях с диском и другими процессами это продумана фича Selenium, но при этом оно должна быть настраиваемая. Что лично для меня крайне странно что эта "проблема" нигде не обсуждается, искал на соседнем форуме - но пусто.

Comment: думаю не обязательно, тесты внутри ссылаются на `IWebDriver` по этому в теории при замене браузера ничего сломаться не должно. А разве будет разное поведение например на FF или IE? phantomJs - это по сути headless?

Comment: обновил ответ. да, вы правы. она как раз решает вашу задачу без docker, vm.

Comment: так это headless? Если да то это я и в хроме могу сделать и на данный момент headless мод мне не нужен - так как я хочу видеть что мой браузер делает на момент написания тестов.

Comment: да, headless. В момент написания тестов используйте хромдрайвер, когда нужно автоматически запускать - используйте PhantomJSDriver. если браузер последней версии, то можно  в ChromeDriver добавить режим "--headless".

Comment: да это я знаю. Но я писал в вопросе что headless не подходит :)

Comment: @AntonKomyshan, а почему не подходит, кстати? При отладке понятно - нужно вдеть. А когда уже все работает, то зачем смотреть?